# HTML5 Slideshow note working (carousel) button not working

Tags: html, carousel, slideshow

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
<img src="C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/auto/cars/sliders/slider1.png" alt="BMW" 
style="width:100%;" >
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/auto/cars/sliders/slider2.png" alt="BMW" 
style="width:130%;" >
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/auto/cars/sliders/slider3.png" alt="BMW" 
style="width:100%;" >
</div>
</div>
<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

[this is my slideshow not working buttons i need help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO39U.png) 
 BUTTON NEXT AND PREVIOUS NOT WORKING.
this is my code 
need help
help need 
i coppied this code from w3school website slideshow using carousel and i edited only src images that located in my desktop but the slideshow not working i dont know why can anyone explain to me why and thank you this is my first time using stackoverflow thank you .

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would done the job for you:

```
$('a[data-slide="prev"]').click(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
});

$('a[data-slide="next"]').click(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
});
```

Comment: i put it no change :((